# CIFilter returns incorrectly positioned CIImage

Tags: swift, core-image, cifilter, ciimage

I am using CIFilter to rotate an image. It is rotating properly. However, when I set imageView.image = result, the image does not fit in the imageView but flows outside. That is very strange because if I render the image by using UIGraphicsImageRenderer, everything is fine.

I share example images and reproducible code;

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet private weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    openPhotoLibrary()
}

func openPhotoLibrary() {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = false
    self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
}

extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage.rawValue)] as? UIImage
    
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: { [weak self] in
        
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPerspectiveRotate")
        
        // let's say I want to rotate it by 50 degrees
        let radian: CGFloat = CGFloat(Double.pi) / (180 / 50)
        filter?.setValue(radian, forKey: "inputRoll")
       
        if let img = image, var image = CIImage(image: img) {
            
            let cgOrientation = img.imageOrientation.cgImagePropertyOrientation
            image = image.oriented(forExifOrientation: Int32(cgOrientation.rawValue))
            
            filter?.setValue(image, forKey: "inputImage")
            
            if let skewed = filter?.outputImage {
                let image = UIImage(ciImage: skewed)
                self?.imageView.image = image
                self?.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            }
        }
    })
  }
 }
```

The white border is the imageView's border color.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason that causes this problem.

this was the wrong way to get UIImage from the output;

```
let image = UIImage(ciImage: skewed)
```

Instead, I should get UIImage in this way;

```
UIImage(cgImage: CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(skewed, from: skewed.extent)!)
```